# Proving that a metric is an ultrametric

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

We have a metric space defined as the following:

Let $X$ be the collection of all sequences of positive integers. If $x=(n_j)_{j=1}^\infty$ and $y=(m_j)_{j=1}^\infty$ are two elements of $X$, set

$$k(x,y)=\inf\{j:n_j\neq m_j\}$$ and

$$d(x,y)= \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if $x=y$} \\ \frac{1}{k(x,y)} & \text{if $x \neq y$} \end{cases}$$

I need to prove that this is an ultrametric space, ie. that $d(x,z) \leq \max\{d(x,y),d(y,z)\}$.

I've proven regular triangle inequality for this same space, but I'm uncertain how to extend that argument to fulfil that of an ultrametric space.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Suppose that $x=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$, $y=\langle y_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$, and $z=\langle z_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$, where the $x_n,y_n$, and $z_n$ are positive integers. The cases in which two of these sequences are equal are pretty easy, so let me deal only with the case in which they’re all distinct. You need to show that $$d(x,z)\le\max\{d(x,y),d(y,z)\}\;,$$ i.e., that

$$\frac1{k(x,z)}\le\max\left\{\frac1{k(x,y)},\frac1{k(y,z)}\right\}\;.$$

This is equivalent to showing that

$$k(x,z)\ge\min\{k(x,y),k(y,z)\}\;.$$

In other words, you want to show that it’s impossible to have

$$k(x,z)<\min\{k(x,y),k(y,z)\}\;:$$

the first term in which $x$ and $z$ differ **cannot** come before the first term at which $y$ differs from at least one of $x$ and $z$.